# is it possible that ordering by priority in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

There are 3 rows

```
| Name  |  State   |
|  1    |  Busy    |
|  2    |  Online  |
|  3    |  Offline |
```

I want to give priority "online" > "busy" > "offline"

```
 heroes = HeroModel.query.\
            filter(HeroModel.id.in_(hero_ids)).\
            order_by(???????). \
            all()
```

How can I order? not by alphabetical order.

Comment: which DB are you connecting to ?

Comment: You should use integers for states and then the ordering would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your select query

```
case state
when 'online' then 1 
when 'offline' then 2
else 3
end as rnk
```

and use order by on this derived column `rnk`

```
order by rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in SQLAlchemy (if you use Oracle or MySQL):

```
heroes = HeroModel.query.\
          filter(HeroModel.id.in_(hero_ids)).\
          order_by(
           case(
               [(HeroModel.state == "online", 0),
                (HeroModel.state == "busy", 1),
                (HeroModel.state == "offline", 2)],
               else_=3). \
         all()
```